# How to use to Algolia connectors together?

Tags: algolia, instantsearch, react-instantsearch

I am working on a project where I'm supposed to implement autocomplete functionality in a search box. I'm using React-InstantSearch and my `SearchBox` component is built up using an Algolia connector `connectSearchBox`. Now I want to implement autocomplete functionality in this same search box using `connectAutoComplete`. I'm confused how these two connectors should go together? Would really appreciate if you guys can help me on this. Thank you!

Link to Autocomplete connector: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/autocomplete/react/?client=jsx

Here's the relevant code:

**SearchBox.jsx**

```
export const SearchBoxBase = ({
  className,
  defaultRefinement,
  variant,
  headerTitle,
}) => {

....
....
....

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {/* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control */}
      <label id="search-input-box" className="fe__searchfield-input-box text-brand-primary">
        { headerTitle || searchText }
      </label>
      <SearchField.Advanced
        className={classNames('fe__searchfield', {
          'fe__searchfield--inverse': variant === STYLE_VARIANTS.inverse,
        })}
        value={defaultRefinement}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        onClear={handleClear}
      >
        <SearchField.Input
          className="form-control-lg"
          aria-labelledby="search-input-box"
          data-nr-synth-id="catalog-search-input-field"
          data-hj-whitelist
        />
        <SearchField.ClearButton data-nr-synth-id="catalog-search-clear-button" />
        <SearchField.SubmitButton data-nr-synth-id="catalog-search-submit-button" />
      </SearchField.Advanced>
    </div>
  );
};


export default connectSearchBox(SearchBoxBase);
```

And this is what I'm planning to add into the SearchBox component:

```
const Autocomplete = ({ hits, currentRefinement, refine }) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input
        type="search"
        value={currentRefinement}
        onChange={event => refine(event.currentTarget.value)}
      />
    </li>
    {hits.map(hit => (
      <li key={hit.objectID}>{hit.name}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const CustomAutocomplete = connectAutoComplete(Autocomplete);
```

The `<input>` tag in my case will be replaced by `<SearchField.Input>` in `SearchBox.jsx`

Comment: How to use two* Algolia connectors together?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to switch your InstantSearch searchbox to be a virtual component and use the Autocomplete searchbox as your primary interface across all pages, including the search page.

Step-by-step guide is here:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/guides/using-instantsearch/